# Is this implementation of a Blocking Queue safe?

Tags: c++, windows, concurrency, queue, blocking

I'm trying to implement a queue which blocks on the Pop operation if it's empty, and unblocks as soon as a new element is pushed. I'm afraid I might have some race condition; I tried to look at some other implementation, but most I found were done in .NET, and the few C++ I found depended too much on other library classes.

```
template <class Element>
class BlockingQueue{
    DRA::CommonCpp::CCriticalSection    m_csQueue;
    DRA::CommonCpp::CEvent              m_eElementPushed;
    std::queue<Element>                 m_Queue;
public:
    void Push( Element newElement ){
        CGuard g( m_csQueue );
        m_Queue.push( newElement );
        m_eElementPushed.set();
    }
    Element Pop(){
        {//RAII block
            CGuard g( m_csQueue );
            bool wait = m_Queue.empty();
        }
        if( wait )
            m_eElementPushed.wait();
        Element first;
        {//RAII block
            CGuard g( m_csQueue );
            first = m_Queue.front();
            m_Queue.pop();
        }
        return first;
    }
};
```

Some explanations are due:

- CCriticalSection is a wrapper for a Windows Critical Section, methods Enter and Leave are private, and CGuard is its only friend
- CGuard is a RAII wrapper for CCriticalSection, enters critical section on constructor, leaves it on destructor
- CEvent is a wrapper for a Windows Event, wait uses the WaitForSingleObject function
- I don't mind that Elements are passed around by value, they are small objects
- I can't use Boost, just Windows stuff (as I have already been doing with CEvent and CGuard)

I'm afraid there might be some weird race condition scenario when using Pop(). What do you guys think?

**UPDATE**: Since I'm working on Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0), I ended up using the unbounded_buffer class provided by the C++ runtime. Of course, I wrapped it in a class using the Pointer to Implementation Idiom (Chesire Cat) just in case we decide to change the implementation or need to port this class to another environment

Comment: The only potential for a data race is the `CEvent` object, that is operated upon both within the critical section in `Push` and outside of the critical section in `Pop`. You should check the multithreading guarantees that your libraries provide.

Comment: Variable `first` is out of scope on return.

Comment: Thanks René, I missed that, fixed it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s not thread safe:

```
    {//RAII block
        CGuard g( m_csQueue );
        bool wait = m_Queue.empty();
    }
    /// BOOM! Other thread ninja-Pop()s an item.
    if( wait )
        m_eElementPushed.wait();
```

Notice the location of the `BOOM` comment. In fact, other locations are also thinkable (after the `if`). In either case, the subsequent `front` and `pop` calls will fail.

Comment: Based on the OP's constraints and Konrad's comment, I suspect the OP will need a push guard and a pop guard... but then I'm not sure how to stop EVERYTHING blocking on the pop.

Comment: True. This might warrant another question (tell me if you think so), but how can I avoid that race condition? I can't lock the whole queue and perform a wait(), that would create a potential deadlock...

Comment: @Peter I had that in my answer but then I noticed that the OP wanted to block the caller thread and yield control to other threads until some data is pushed into the queue. That’s not possible with two locks alone; there also needs to be a wait/signalling mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

[Condition variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682052%28VS.85%29.aspx) should be helpful if you are targetting newest Windows versions.  This typically makes implementing blocking queues simpler.

See [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) for design of a similar queue using Boost - even if you cannot use Boost or condition variables, the general guidance and follow-up discussion there should be useful.

Comment: +1: Great link, explains this scenario's race conditions very well

Comment: See also http://www.manning.com/williams/ (same author, and a member under his own name on SO)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll redo it using Condition Variables

Comment: Just note the following caveat from MSDN: `Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000:  Condition variables are not supported.`

Comment: That's what Boost is for :-)  Sorry you cannot use that.

Comment: If you do not wish to use condvars or need to support the OS listed by Steve, (or any OS, really), use a semaphore signal/wait instead of an event set/wait.  Semaphores have a count & so consumers can only get in to dequeue if there is an entry in the queue for them - no BOOM.

Comment: Another alternative is to abstract the Windows-specific condvar code out of Boost, and pretend to your boss that it's not from Boost.